# Find all the critical points that the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = 2xe^x\sin y$

has if $0 \leq y \leq 2\pi$

I found that the critical points are $(0,0)$, $(0,\pi)$, $(0,2\pi)$, $(-1, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $(-1, \frac{3\pi}{2})$.

I lost points because I also included $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(0, \frac{3\pi}{2})$

Why aren't these latter two included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical points must be satisfied the following equations:

$$2xe^x\cos y=0; \,\,\, 2\sin y(1+x)e^x=0$$